# How can I insert many values into a set via redis-cli or otherwise?

Tags: redis, set

I am using redis-cli. I would like to add in a set the numbers 1 all the way to 4,500,000. How can I accomplish this? The [docs](https://redis.io/commands/sadd) for `sadd` do not mention how to do this. If this would involve having to type or paste in every single integer individually, this obviously won't work in the CLI, so is there another way programatically?

Comment: Are you looking for a single Redis command to add a range of integers to a Set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bash script for doing this.
Use 'seq' to create a list of numbers, loop over it and add the current iteration inside the set

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 10`
do
redis-cli sadd myset  $i
done
```

In case you need to use redis-cli with host and port details, change the command accordingly: redis-cli -h  -p

Once you have this ready in a .sh file, you can run it like:

bash redis_script.sh